# Install Android Studio on Azure VM

Tags: azure, vt-x

I installed android studio on Azure virtual machine. I have the following error in Virtual Device:

`Your CPU does not support VT-x.`

If I try to install XAMS I get the following error:

```
Unable to install Intel® HAXM
Your CPU does not support VT-x.
Unfortunately, your computer does not support hardware accelerated virtualization.
```

Here are some of your options:

1. Use a physical device for testing
2. Develop on a Windows/OSX computer with an Intel processor that supports VT-x and NX
3. Develop on a Linux computer that supports VT-x or SVM
4. Use an Android Virtual Device based on an ARM system image
   (This is 10x slower than hardware accelerated virtualization)

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Comment: Have you tried some of the options?

Answer (score 0):

This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization) will help.

In short you will need to have nested virtualization enabled:

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V -IncludeManagementTools -Restart
```